# Javascript working locally but not on production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have been trying to solve this issue for weeks, but with no succes so instead of looking for the answear in other peoples questions, I thought I should write my own.

The problem is as follows. A couple of weeks ago I finished one of my rails projects, so I pushed the repo to heroku. Everything seemed to work fine, but then I notice that my navbar toogle was not working and my carousel neither. Locally ther work perfectly.

Currently it is hosted on heroku.

These are the things I have tried.

1. Assets precompiled and clean
2. Installed `gem 'rails_12factor'`
3. Reordered app.js as follows

```js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require lightbox
//= require_tree .
//= require owl.carousel
```

4. I even deployed my app to digital ocean(I thought that heroku was the problem)
5. I tried to use a different bootstrap gem. `gem 'bootstrap-sass'`but still the same issue.
   So, basically some of the js is not working the way it should. I even tryed to use a different type of slider named flickity, I downloaded the js and css of flickity, precompile, then push but in heroku seems to be broken.
6. Followed the nex stackoverflow questions:

Here is my code:

production.rb

```ruby
config.serve_static_files = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

Gemfile

```ruby
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'lightbox2-rails'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'owlcarousel-rails'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem "rmagick"
gem "carrierwave"
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'sprockets_better_errors'
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano',         require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
end
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'draper'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'rails'
gem "puma"
gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
```

aplication.css

```css
 *= require lightbox
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= require owl.carousel
 *= require owl.theme
```

console error

```css
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function(…)
```

This error may explain why the carousel does not work. But I have tryed another ones and the they dont work either. And what about the navbar toogle?

There is this one too

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bridge' of undefined(…)`

If you need any more information let me know please.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: There you go @Preston

Comment: Is the file for the `carousel` function being loaded?

Comment: How can I check that? @Preston

Comment: In the dev tools look at the resources and the file should be in the Scripts folder.

Comment: Yes, it is being loaded.@Preston

Comment: Now that you mentioned, comparing the files that are being loaded locally to the ones being load in production, the ones locally are a lot more. @Preston

Comment: Are you compressing the .js assets in production?

Comment: No, should I? @Preston

Comment: try `config.assets.debug = true` in your production.rb file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156504/discussion-between-ezequiel-and-preston).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `config.assets.debug = true` in your production.rb file and see if that fixes it.  I'm guessing there is an error in the middle of your compressed JS file causing the rest of the functions to not be executed.